# Black spots on screen, go away when that part of screen is active

Tags: nvidia, cuda, nvidia-geforce

Every once in a while, parts (or all) of my screen will go black. If I run my mouse over the area, or activate that part of the screen by clicking on the window it's covering, the black goes away in that area.

It seems to especially happen when the computer is working hard and the computer starts to feel hot in one area. But even when it's not, there's a small black rectangle at the very top of my screen that acts the same way:
[image: BlackSpotAboveDate]

This has happened ever since installing CUDA for my Nvidia Geforce GPU... could I have installed something incorrectly?

Comment: I see that happening in my VM's occasionally.  These usually go away if I update the system.

Comment: Mine is dual boot. It was fixed temporarily by a firmware update, but came back.